# App logo positioned half in the ActionBar and half on the mainActivty screen

Tags: android, android-layout

Can something like this be achieved in Android? my guess is not since you can specify 2 different layouts one for the ActionBar and one for the Activity, but I may also be mistaken

[image]

Comment: Yes, it can bee achieved. My idea is to make your own ActionBar and to user FrameLayout to put  icon on the position that you want.

Comment: I have implemented my own ActionBar layout before  but I couldn't put icons in the middle of actionbar and activity screen

Comment: Did you try Framelayout that contains layout for icon and layout for all other stuff?

Comment: No but the end of a layout should end at the end of the ActionBar I cannot overcome this..

Comment: You could kinda cheat, and use a PopupWindow that overlaps the ActionBar and main layout.

Comment: how could I use a popupWindow ? wouldn't it take all the focus? I never used it before that's why i'm asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a much more solid solution than the `PopupWindow` previously suggested.

The layout for the logo overlay is a simple `ImageView`, on which we've set the `clickable` attribute to `true` to prevent touch events from propagating through to `View`s underneath.

`logo.xml` layout:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

This method is meant to work with the old `ActionBar`, and relies on the home `View` as the anchor for the overlay. It is, however, easily modified to work with the support `Toolbar` class and its logo `View`, though that is probably unnecessary, since the `Toolbar` class is a `View` that can be easily setup and manipulated in layout XML.

```
private void showLogoOverlay() {
    final View anchor = findViewById(android.R.id.home);
    if(anchor == null) {
        return;
    }

    final View overlay = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.logo, null, false);
    final ViewGroup decor = (ViewGroup) getWindow().getDecorView();

    anchor.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right,
                                       int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop,
                                       int oldRight, int oldBottom) {

                int[] offset = new int[2];
                anchor.getLocationOnScreen(offset);

                decor.addView(overlay, 200, 200);
                overlay.setX(offset[0]);
                overlay.setY(offset[1]);

                anchor.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! just gimme some time to check it!

Comment: Ok don't worry about that I know how to make a custom Layout for the ActionBar only the place of the Icon troubles me, I get back to you if I stumble upon any problems

Comment: hey sorry I was away I've just tried your code..It works great thanks so much I just have a problem when calling pop.showAsDropDown it needs lowest API 19 is there any workaround for API 10 and above?

Comment: sorry to bother you again I've tested my app in android 4.4 and the popup  is stuck next to the left border of the screen.This doesn't happen in 2.3.3 Do you know what I could try? sorry again...

Comment: I'm using ActionBarSherlock