# How do I make an app icon that flows out of the action-bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My goal is to have the icon appear in the place you would usually see it, but extend it slightly below the bottom of the bar. There seems to be no standard way to do this, so I imagine some kind of overlaying is involved.

The result would be something like this:
[image]

Comment: What if... You set the bavkground of the action bar to have less height and be half transparent?? You can set a square background with fixed height http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310362/android-shape-background . Or by percent.

Comment: You might have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176096/app-logo-positioned-half-in-the-actionbar-and-half-on-the-mainactivty-screen/25177098#25177098